# Stack Exchange tags sets : exclude tag

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, tag-filters

Tag sets in Stack Exchange are very useful, and I particularly like the wild card, however, I think it would be even more useful if it were possible to add an "except tag(s)" to the sets.

For example, *word* covers not only the Office product (msword, word-vba, word-2007) but also wordpress, so it would be good to be able to exclude a common tag that does not fit in with a wild card selection.

Comment: my regular stackoverflow points havent cascaded over so I can't vote this up yet but .. me too! particularly for tags like [ruby] .. being able to -rails would greatly improve the tag for actual ruby questions instead of rails questions. I'd guess that half or more of the [ruby] tagged questions are really about the rails library, not about the language specifically.

Comment: I was trying to find an answer to a curl question, and was not interested in the php curl implementation. Most of the questions wer about the php implementation. It would have been great to be able to say something like "[curl] -[php]" to exclude those topics. Maybe I would have actually found what I was looking for, in that case.