# Add "I'd like to exclude..." option to Stack Exchange filters

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Stack Exchange tags sets : exclude tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72532/stack-exchange-tags-sets-exclude-tag)

Here's my filter: https://stackexchange.com/filters/26689/mod-rewrite

That's pretty nice, but I'd like to exclude stuff that have the [iis](/questions/tagged/iis) tag.

Sometimes (hopefully not often) I'm losing some time trying to read and understand questions I'll never be able to answer, and I guess maybe I'm not the only one in this situation.

So, the Stack Exchange filters options, there's the `1. Which questions do you want to include?` and I was wondering: how about adding an option, or a sub-question... or maybe a `2. Which questions do you want to exclude?`?